# Move vsFTPd user to another server

Tags: linux, ftp, vsftpd

We have a server with many vsFTPd FTP users saved in /etc/vsftpd/users/* and /etc/vsftpd/passwd.db. As me made a new server to split the load, we have to move some of the users to the new server.

Copying the user file should be simple but how can we move the password hash so the user can log in with his credentials to the new machine?

We don't want to copy everyone over so we can't move that entire thing, just move some selected users to the other server without resetting their passwords.

Thank you!

Comment: This fully depends on how you configured the user authentication in vsftpd.conf

Comment: I can't find any authentication option in the /etc/vsftpd.conf so I think it's on default but I found these lines if that helps:
# allow virtual users:
guest_enable=YES
virtual_use_local_privs=YES
user_config_dir=/etc/vsftpd/users
We have a management system that manages the creation of ftp users so I never had to manage vsFTPd itself or touch the configs.

Comment: ... well, if you have a management system for users, then that is what you need to understand to know how to back up users, right?

Comment: Well they are stored in the passwd.db file and the users folder so backing these up would mean they can be put back. The problem is that I don't know how I can read the hashes of single users from the passwd.db or how I can change the users hash on the other server later.

Comment: ah, sorry, I completely missed the point of your question there!

Answer (score 1):

your .db file is (if I'm not completely mistaken) a Berkeley DB, and while I'm not really a fan nor very experienced with these, you should be able to open that database file using a berkeley db driver for your favourite scripting language.

For Python, that'd be [berkeleydb](https://pypi.org/project/berkeleydb/).

Comment: oof i'm writing in powershell, lets see what I can do! Thanks!

Comment: Ok I wasn't able to find anything, time to learn python then :/

Comment: I think you'll find powershell can be pretty limited for things that involved checking lists of strings against each other, anyway :) Luckily, if you're good with powershell, python will not be hard, I guess.

Comment: Honestly, though, these ancient key/value databases are kind of annoying to work with – in any language.

Comment: Powershell is my personal fav so I start my projects with it. Can Berkley DB be accessed in a way line "Connect -> read value" and "Connect -> write value" so I can make a oneliner in python or is it more complex where you need more then that?

Comment: you need to "create db; db.open(db_file); db.do_something(...); db.close()" to put it in pseudocode. It's not really complex, but it's not a oneliner, either. It's not a database *server* (like say MySQL) that you *connect* to, it's an embeddable database, a very rudimentary one.